# Аргументы scanf для unsigned long long int

Tags: c, переменные

Нужно считать `unsigned long long int` через `scanf`, но я не знаю - какие аргументы стоит использовать. 
Спасибо

Comment: `%llu` надо полагать...

Comment: Точно? Если да - то спасибо

Comment: @VTT, напишите это в ответ пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, AnT
Короче,  `%llu`- работает

Comment: Во-первых, спасибо вам надо @VTT говорить - это его ответ. Во-вторых, тут у нас не форум и "общаться" через ответы тут не принято.

Answer (score -2):

Формат `unsigned long long` для `scanf` должен быть `%Lu`, вообще эта информация легко доступна из [man](http://ru.manpages.org/fscanf/3).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78516/discussion-on-answer-by-newview--scanf--unsigned-long-long-int).